# How to return the correct start date value from a stored procedure in this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using below case condition to calculate a `StartDate` variable:

```
DECLARE @StartDate Date =
   DATEADD(DAY, CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 2 THEN -10 ELSE -8 END, GETDATE())
```

AS you can see, if today's date is Monday then 10 days are subtracted from today's date, else 8 days are deducted. Since today (10/16/2018) is not a Monday, this would return 10/8/2018 as an output (8 days deduction). If executed on Monday (10/15) then `@StartDate` would return 10/5 as output.

I added a table called `Holidays` and it has two columns `Holiday Name` and `Date` containing three records for this year: Columbus Day: 10/8, Veteran day 11/12 and Thanksgiving 11/22.

Now the challenging part I have to do is, if the returned output of `@StartDate` is 10/8 (query executed today: 10/16) which is a holiday (Monday), then value of `@StartDate` should be changed to 10/5 (previous business day, Saturday & Sunday excluded). Also if the value of `@StartDate` is 10/5 (query executed on 10/15), then the value should be changed to 10/4 since 10/8 was a holiday, it won't be counted for deduction of 10 days so instead of 10/5, it should be 10/4.

So in theory it should work as: check if there are any holidays that fall between today's date and `@StartDate`, and if so then use prior day and adjust for Mondays accordingly based on the scenario I mentioned above.

Please note that the included statement I mentioned at the top is part of a stored procedure.

How can I make this work, can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this just the start of the process? In the future will you possible have multiple holidays one after the other or is it only ever a single day?

Comment: [Just use a calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) of **all the days**, not just the holidays, and mark them appropriately. Building all this logic into the query, you're going to leave out exceptions (like a two-day holiday, holidays on Mondays), someone with a different `DATEFIRST` is going to run that code and get wrong results, etc. etc. This problem has been solved; don't re-solve it.

Comment: Tips: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`. Don't count on multiple calls to `GetDate()` returning the same value, capture it once, e.g. `declare @Today as Date = Cast( GetDate() as Date);`, and use that value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there are never multiple dates in a row in your holiday, this will do it in a single(ish) statement. You could easily break this into two if you prefer:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date

;with d as (
select convert(date,dateadd(day,case when datepart(dw,getdate())=2 then -10 else -8 end,getdate())) dt
)
select @StartDate=case when holiday.date is null then dt else dateadd(day,-1,dt) end
from d 
left join holiday on holiday.date=dt
```

EDIT: This is a complete working copy. I create a table variable to hold holidays, run the initial query, then insert the returned date as a holiday, then run the query again. If you run this in sql server you will see that the second query returns the day before the first query.

```
declare @holiday table(date date)
DECLARE @StartDate date

;with d as (
select convert(date,dateadd(day,case when datepart(dw,getdate())=2 then -10 else -8 end,getdate())) dt
)
select @StartDate=case when holiday.date is null then dt else dateadd(day,-1,dt) end
from d 
left join @holiday holiday on holiday.date=dt

select @startdate

insert @holiday values (@startdate)

;with d as (
select convert(date,dateadd(day,case when datepart(dw,getdate())=2 then -10 else -8 end,getdate())) dt
)
select @StartDate=case when holiday.date is null then dt else dateadd(day,-1,dt) end
from d 
left join @holiday holiday on holiday.date=dt

select @startdate
```

Comment: Thanks TomC. The holiday dates are fixed and they will be updated in the next year

Comment: There are about 10 holidays that will come in a year and that is the only time it needs to be accounted

Comment: Whenever an output of StartDate equals one of the date fields mentioned in the Datatable then we need to perform condition check as I mentioned in the description

Comment: Thanks @mdevm, the question is what happens if there are two holidays in a row. Do we need to go back multiple days?

Comment: nope not needed. The scenario would come into picture only when StartDate output equals any of the federal holidays listed here: https://www.federalreserve.gov/aboutthefed/k8.htm

Comment: I am seeing an error as "Incorrect syntax near dt" by the first select statement of your answer.

Comment: I can send you a screenshot if needed,let me know. Or I can send you the stored proc to look at if that helps, that way you will understand the process better Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for the update. Slightly confused, my table name is HolidayTable so as per your query, how should I update so that way Date fields from HolidayTable is referenced correctly. The goal is to check Date field from HolidayTable

Comment: So something like select @StartDate= case when DBName.dbo.HolidayTable.Date is null, not sure.

Comment: The second example is a self-contained one to show there are no syntax errors. You can cut and paste that right into your query window and it will work. You can use that as a guide to fixing up your own. The first example I posted is closer to what you need, with the table Holiday replaced by your table name HolidayTable.

Comment: Are you referring to the edit part? I was getting syntax error in the first example so wasn't able to test. I am new to SQL so that is why was wondering if you could help with necessary steps, thanks in advance. My table name is HolidayTable and column name is Date.

Comment: I would go back and look at your code from the first part. The second self-contained example is to prove that there is no syntax error, so must be something in how you tried to stick it into your code. You should be able to do it. If not, you would have to edit your question and post your actual stored proc (cut out whatever is not necessary) that gives a syntax error. My first example should just work in place of the line you posted, changing my table `Holiday` to yours `HolidayTable`.

Comment: Okay I see, I was able to make that table change. But for some reason its not executing correctly.Looks like its ignoring the holiday date from HolidayTable.

Comment: I think you will need to post the actual stored proc, as there must be something else going on.